# How to create a table in MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql

My connection is alright and it is getting connected to MySQL database. But I cannot create table inside a database...?

```
public static void CreateTable () throws SQLException
{


    try {
            Connection con = DBConnection();
            String statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first VARCHAR(225), last VARCHAR(225) PRIMARY KEY(id)";
            PreparedStatement create = con.prepareStatement(statement);
            create.executeUpdate(); 
            System.out.println("Table created...!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Could not create table...!");

        }
```

Comment: Hey there, I am a little rusty on this way, but by chance are you not passing the query to the database? I see you prepare a statement but never passed it through.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What do the logs say?

Comment: Also you're missing a trailing `)` on `String statement`

Comment: Error is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I have tried to pass the query like "create.executeUpdate(statement)"
but I have same error

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try this

Use `Connection.createStatement()`, and then

```
Statement.executeUpdate​("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first VARCHAR(225), last VARCHAR(225) PRIMARY KEY(id)");
```

A PreparedStatement is for statements you're going to pass parameters to, which it doesn't appear that you're doing.

Good luck.